# JS : Convert Array of Strings to Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, prototype

i have this array of **strings** :

```
let myArray : ["AA","BB" , "CC" ...]
```

I want to convert it to an **array of objects**:

```
myArray  = [{"id":1 , "value": "AAA"},{"id":2 , "value": "BBB"},{"id":3 , "value": "CCC"}...]
```

I ve trie with **"let for"**:

```
for (let obj of  ListObj) {
      let resObj = {};
      resObj ['value'] = obj  ;
      equipment = resObj ;
}
```

And with **map** :

```
ListObj.map(obj => { 'value' = obj })
```

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `.map()` for this. It passes the index into the callback.

```
myArray = myArray.map((str, index) => ({ value: str, id: index + 1 }));
```

Comment: Life saver. God bless