# Convert List into JSON array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

suppose i have list something Like

```
let li = ["Agartala*","Belonia","Dharmanagar","Kailasahar","Khowai""Pratapgarh","Udaipur"]
```

i want convert it into JSON with key value like :

```
{ {"city" : "Agartala*"} ,
  {"city" : "Belonia"},
  {"city" : "Dharmanagar"}, 
  {"city" : "Kailasahar"}, 
  {"city" : "Khowai"},
    ....   }
```

Comment: `li.map(city => ({city}})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS : Convert Array of Strings to Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726504/js-convert-array-of-strings-to-array-of-objects)

Comment: That's not a valid output? did you mean `[ {...}, {...} ]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = li.map(function (value, key) {
    return {
        "city": value,
    }
});
```

Comment: (without `JSON.stringify` this function does not return JSON, it will return an array)