# String-split into array of objects

Tags: typescript

I am trying to split a string into an array of objects in TS.
I have the following (example) string:

`Example1,Example2,Example3,Example4,Example5`

And I'm trying to parse it into:

```
    [
       {
          "id":"Example1"
       },
       {
          "id":"Example2"
       },
       {
          "id":"Example3"
       },
       {
          "id":"Example4"
       },
       {
          "id":"Example5"
       }
    ]
```

using split() i can easily split it into an array of strings, but that doesn't quite cover my use case in this instance.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS : Convert Array of Strings to Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726504/js-convert-array-of-strings-to-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaScript Array method `map`. You can perform any transformation over array items with it, such as turning them into plain objects.

[Mdn docs on Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

In your case, you want something like:
`myString.split(",").map(el => ({ id: el });`

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer in typescript:

```
interface Output {
    id: string
}

const initialString: string = 'Example1,Example2,Example3,Example4,Example5';

const finalArray: Output[] = [].concat(initialString.split(',').map(item => {
    return { id: item }
}))
```

Answer (score -1):

If your string items have always the same length, (always follow a standar format like "id1,id2,id3" or "part1.part2,part3") you could use .substring(index from, index to+1)

Like this:

```
var array : string[] = []; 

//string.length+4 will allow to susbtring the last item of the string
for(var n = 0; n < (string.length+4); i++){

  //taking "id1" as an example, substring from 0 - 4 whill return "id1" 
  array.push(string.substring(n, n+4));
 // adding +4 to n will make it substring from after the comma on the next 
 //iteration and return "id2"
  n += 4;

}
```

This way you should try to create a standar to your string items

Here's some doc to substring :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_substring.htm